# JavaScript: Can't access array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm experiencing extremely strange behavior when accessing a property of an object.

Running this code:

```
console.log(myObj);
console.log(myObj.items);
console.log(myObj);
```

I get this output in the console:

[image]

How could this possibly happen?

Comment: We probably need more information than that.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not much information is provided, but the question looks clear to me. Why would JavaScript show a 2-element array in an object, but when the array is accessed directly, it shows a 0-element array?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I mean, are all the `console.log` exactly one after each other? Was the console already opened when the code was executed? They all can contribute to this result.

Comment: Because chrome only evaluates the object when unfolded, which probably means, `myObj.items` is populated later on

Comment: are you shure you don't have method called `items` in your object ... prototype is not expanded so i can not see that

Comment: @Reflective Clearly from the console `items` is an Array not a function.

Comment: I'm not blind Derek, i can see that, but if you have same method defined ... what do you think about that? can you see prototype ? NO ... so don't tell me it's clear

Comment: You can try the same in FireBug ... console will show the count of elements in array almost in real time . Firefox with FireBug: `console.log({a: [1,2,3], b:'c'});`  outputs `Object { a=[3], b="c"}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`console.log`, during execution, outputs a string representation of the value in the console. Depending on Chrome's mood, it might show something `[object Object]` or something like `Object {}`. That doesn't matter.

Now note the little blue `i` beside it. What it means is that the object has been modified between the time it was logged and the time you expanded it in the console, and it now shows the *current value* (with the 2 items), not the value during `console.log`'s execution (no items). You can actually hover on the blue `i` to get the explanation.

To replicate the issue, open the console and run this snippet:

```js
var obj = {arr: []};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.arr);
console.log(obj);

// by this time, you see 2 object logs, 1 empty array
// (representation differs from time to time)
// > Object
// []
// > Object

obj.arr.push(1,2);

// when you try to expand the objects, an array of 2 items magically appear
// but you still see the empty array ([]) in the log.
```

This behavior differs across browsers. As far as I remember, Firebug outputs a serialized version when `console.log` executes, hence this doesn't happen there.

#### Debugging the code

To debug this kind of code, you have several options:

- The quickest way is to log the stringified version of the object using `JSON.stringify`, like `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`;
- The best way is to add a breakpoint via the Sources tab. Browse to your file in the Sources tab of the Dev Tools, and add a breakpoint in that position. Run your code, and it will pause at that point. Use the Scope panel to inspect the variables.
- If you can't reach the code using a breakpoint (probably run using `eval` or injected in the console), you can use the `debugger;` statement. Just put it in the code at that position. Run the code and it will pause when it reaches the statement. Use the Scope panel in Sources tab to inspect.

Answer (score 2):

With so little information, I can only assume you're dynamically populating the `items` property, making it empty when the 2nd console log runs.

Now you're wondering why it is there in the 1st console log: the console doesn't show the object properties that were there at the time the object was logged, but rather at the time the object entry was expanded in the console, so it could be that the `items` were populated after your 2nd console log and before you expanded the 1st one. Try logging the object as a string or a JSON to see its actual state at the time the console log was run.

---

Bottom line: **object properties in the dev console get updated only when you expand the object entry (when you click the arrow)** so you're not seeing the actual representation of the object from the time it was logged.

Here's a simple demonstration - see how it can even turn from an array into a string:

```js
var obj = {p: []}
console.log(obj);
setTimeout(function(){
  obj.p = "I'm not even an array!";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: probably this can be avoided by defining object .toString() metod which dumps the size of the array, this metod will be executed on display so, even display is delayed metod and not executes immediately will give more reliable result in console, but toJSON is much easier

Comment: I already said that: `"Try logging the object as a string or a JSON to see its actual state at the time the console log was run."`

Comment: my comment was incomplete, i added a note that toJSON is much easier, sorry

Comment: Oh no problem, but I mentioned the JSON as well: `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` works just fine.

Comment: :) in the note I said that what you told is much easier ... you got me wrong.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant. :)

Comment: console.log({a: [1,2,3], b:'c'}); FF with FireBug:  Object { a=[3],  b="c"} ... chrome is not always the best solution for debuging.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the JSON representation of the object to check, you can do that with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 2));
```